# Array with int and char in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I need to put 3 strings on an `array[3][3]`.

I tried to do it with pointers, but I only receive a single character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[3][3]
char thing[5] = "thing";

main()
{
    thing = array[0][0];
    printf("%s", array[0][0];
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to print out the integer stored in `array[0][0]` as text?  If so, use `%d` format specifier, not `%s`.

Comment: `thing = array[0][0];` makes no sense, arrays are immutable in C. `char thing[5] = "thing";` makes no sense, strings are `'\0'`-terminated in C.

Comment: Be careful please, your array is defined as int.

Comment: `array[0][0]` is an integer (`int`), not a string, and even the array `thing` does not contain a valid C string since you specified the `[5]` which does not leave room for the `'\0'` terminator. I'm sorry but I can't figure out what you're trying to do, and it's not because of your English, but because of the C code (it does not compile and it doesn't show what you're trying to accomplish).

Comment: @EOF `char thing[5] = "thing"` is perfectly valid.  It initialises the array but there is no null-terminator, so you cannot use many of the functions from the string library on it.

Comment: @EOF arrays are not “immutable in C” - string _literals_ are, but `thing[5]` is a mutable array of 5 characters initialised to contain `'t', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g'`. It makes sense and is valid C, it's just not a C string because of the lack of terminating NUL. Removing the `5` would make it an array of _6_ characters (automatically counted by the compiler to include the NUL) - it would be a valid string, but still mutable because it's only initialised from a string literal, not a pointer to one.

Comment: @Arkku: No. *arrays* **are** immutable. Their *contents* may be mutable, but the array itself is not.

Comment: @EOF Ah, you meant the assignment to `thing` - that is indeed wrong since `thing` is not a pointer. But saying “arrays are immutable” is wrong, since an immutable array would be a `const` array, which this isn't. Correct would be something like “you cannot assign to an array” (or, more technically, “arrays are not lvalues”).

Comment: @EOF I just wanted to add that I did not wish to sound hostile; I do get your point about the address of the array being unassignable, but I don't agree with the terminology: by that argument one might say that, e.g., `int i` is immutable because `&i = p` is invalid, and only the contents of `i` (a single `int`) are mutable… An array is not a pointer, so there is no immutable pointer there to which assignment is not allowed. There's just the array, which _is_ it's contents and _nothing more_, thus it is mutable if the contents are mutable. =)

Comment: Don't post code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @EOF You are confused. Arrays are their content -- a contiguous series of like elements. `array` isn't an array, it's a symbol (that *refers to* an array), and it cannot be assigned to. Consider `int** arr = array` ... now `arr` refers to the same array that `array` refers to.

Comment: @Arkku that's why i'm question, i can't do it or i don't know how can i do it, it was an example.

Comment: @JimBalter I post to get some help, i was doing some exercises and find this but i couldn't do it.
The exercise request me to do:
- Do a menu.
- First: Get 3 variables to a archive
Number (DNI/Passport/etc.), String (Address), String (Name and Last Name)
- Second: Get other 3 variables to a archive
Number (DNI/Passport/etc.), String (State), String (Location)
- Third: Do a new archive with the other 2
Number (DNI/Passport/etc.), String (Address), String (Name and Last Name), String (State), String (Location)
- Third: Do a new archive with the other 2

Comment: @Arkku I was trying to do it with arrays (A "box" array) but i couldn't put strings on it, i try to do it with pointers but i couldn't.

Comment: @JimBalter I was trying to do it with arrays (A "box" array) but i couldn't put strings on it, i try to do it with pointers but i couldn't

Comment: " I post to get some help" -- Yes, so? Don't post code that doesn't compile. And my other comment wasn't addressed to you. Finally, SO is not a substitute for skills or abilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. With due respect your code absolutely incorrect and need many changes. You need to update your programming skills too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char array[3][6]={0};
char *thing = "this";

main()
{
    strcpy(array[0],thing);
    printf("%s\n", array[0]);
}
```

Comment: That was close to what I wanted, thank you. After talking to my teachers, I said it was impossible (and are able to explain the problem in my language).

Comment: @Dash95 glad to see response helped.